# Display a button content Hi in navigation bar by default when page loads

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please help me in solving the below problem

I have a navigation bar , with 3 buttons : 
1. home 2. info 3. restart

info and restart buttons are php pages . 
1. home button , displays a content written inside

I want to display the home button content by default when page loads . 
Currently how my navigation bar works is , it fetches all 3 tabs content and hides it . It displays the content only when clicking on the buttons . 
Below is the code

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
<style>
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

/* Style the tab */
div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
</style>
```

```html
<body>
<div class="tab" >
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Home')" id="defaultOpen"><b>Home</b></button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Info')"><b>Info</b></button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Restart')"><b>Restart</b></button>
</div>
<div id="Home" class="tabcontent">
  <h3><font face="arial" /><u>Information About Web Page</u></h3>

  <p>
  Hello World ! 
</p>
</div>
<div id="Info" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Information</h3>
  <p>
<?php
        include('a.php');
     ?></p>
</div>

<div id="Restart" class="tabcontent">
  <h3><font face="arial" />restart</h3>
  <p>
<?php
        include('restart.php');
        ?></p>

</div>
</body>
```

When i use document.getElementById("defaultOpen").focus(); im not able to open home tab by default when page loads .

Comment: `I want to display the home button content by default when page loads ` .yes its working good ...its showing default home button and content

Comment: Yes it is showing here when you run the code snippet . But when i execute with the actual php files , it is not showing . I had to manually click on the home button .

Comment: ok, let check my answer

Comment: Not clear what is your problem ?

Comment: When page loads , i want home tab content to display by default when page loads . But its not displaying .

Comment: since i have included 2 php files for other tabs , i had to name my file with .php extension . when I name with .php extension , my page is loading but i had to click on the tab every time. But if , I rename my file with .html , home page is auto displayed but my other two tabs are not showing .php file content .

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is showing Hi, until you click another menu item. Then it grabs the `altText` attribute and displays that text.

Is that what you want?

```js
function openCity(evt, cityName) {
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
    tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
    for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
        tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
    for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
        tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
    evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
    
    var defaultOpen = document.getElementById('defaultOpen');
    defaultOpen.getElementsByTagName('b')[0].innerHTML = defaultOpen.getAttribute('altTxt');
}

// Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
//document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
<style>
body {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}

/* Style the tab */
div.tab {
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Style the buttons inside the tab */
div.tab button {
    background-color: inherit;
    float: left;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    transition: 0.3s;
    font-size: 17px;
}

/* Change background color of buttons on hover */
div.tab button:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

/* Create an active/current tablink class */
div.tab button.active {
    background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the tab content */
.tabcontent {
    display: none;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-top: none;
}
</style>
```

```html
<body>
<div class="tab" >
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Home')" id="defaultOpen" altTxt="Home"><b>Hi</b></button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Info')"><b>Info</b></button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Restart')"><b>Restart</b></button>
</div>
<div id="Home" class="tabcontent" style="display: block">
  <h3><font face="arial" /><u>Information About Web Page</u></h3>

  <p>Hello World !</p>
</div>
<div id="Info" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Information</h3>
  <p>
<?php
        include('a.php');
     ?></p>
</div>

<div id="Restart" class="tabcontent">
  <h3><font face="arial" />restart</h3>
  <p>
<?php
        include('restart.php');
        ?></p>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: no . I want the tab Home to retain . I'm button home with id "defaultOpen" , which in turn calls the function ,document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click(); . But its not working when i check it in my browser .

Comment: @naruto Do you have javascript disabled in your browser?

Comment: No , I guess . Bcoz , only , document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click(); is not working and other java scripts are working .

Answer (score 0):

Do this, perform the home click action on after body load.It will auto trigger home click.

Add change your body tag like this

```
<body onload="openCity(event, 'Home')">

//others code

</body>
```

Comment: even this is not working Prasanth . When i manually click on button , my home page is displayed